# NumPy - Get bounds of array representing bounding boxes

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of shape `(N, 4)` holding data in the form of:

```
[[min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y],
 [min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y],
 ...,
 [min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y]]
```

and I need generate an array of shape `(4,)` such that:

```
[smallest_min_x, smallest_min_y, largest_max_x, largest_max_y]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is `arr`, you can use:

```
np.concatenate((np.amin(arr, 0)[:2], np.amax(arr, 0)[2:]))
```

This calculates the minimums and maximums along the axes, selects the ones required, and concatenates them.